# Can't debug Java program in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

For the first time I encounter problem when I can't debug Java program in Intellij IDEA. Output to command line works, but breakpoint is ignored..
May be it's because I created Maven configuration to start the program.
It might be that I'm disconnected from JVM, but I have no idea how to connect to.
What can be the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: did you try a clean build?  are you sure you are running with a debug task?  is this a standalone java program or something running in a container?

Comment: Hi, this is standalone java program. I described the process I do as comment to another answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about debugging something running in Maven with IntelliJ, you can

1. Run the maven build through IntelliJ and debug it like anything else, or
2. Run your build using `mvnDebug` instead of just `mvn`. It will wait for a debugger to connect on port 8000. You can have IntelliJ do this by creating a Run/Debug Configuration of type "Remote" that connects to localhost:8000.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I created a configuration in IDEA analogous to the command line version: mvn clean test -P launch. So, I'm using first option you wrote. But it simply doesn't stop

Comment: Thank you @Ryan, second way is working. If you can help me with first one, would be very nice!

Comment: Surefire [forks a process](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html) for running tests, which can mess with debugging. One way to overcome it is by adding `-DforkMode=never` to your mvn command line (put it in the "Goals" box in IntelliJ).

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing with non-triggered breakpoints, see following:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003676199-Can-t-debug-any-Java-or-Kotlin-application

In my case disabling android plugins solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

That solution was worked for me;

> `File-->Invalidate Caches-->Tick The Clear CheckBoxes --> Restart`

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was the following in IntelliJ. Go to:

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner

Make sure to uncheck the box 'Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven'

After that, I could debug and the breakpoints worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Maven and IDEA use separate build processes. Ironically I only managed today to get my own app built,deployed and run in browser today using:
Maven 3.0
Tomcat 7.0.5 with tomcat-maven-plugin
IDEA IU version 10

So ask if you need a hand.

Yucca

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same bug in the Java VM, I just ran into:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6862295

The stated workaround was to use the -XX:+UseParallelGC on the Java VM.

It's not an IDE problem.

Comment: but:  `Error running Unnamed
         Invalid arguments : Already listening
         [timeout, port, localAddress]`